# Assigning null to a map element

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have been doing some reading and trying to learn more about maps and json. I have a list of maps that have nested maps. The nested maps may be empty so I am trying to learn how to deal with them.

I get json from an API:

```
[{
'addressLine1' : "2880 La Quinta Dr",
'city' : "Missouri City",
'state' : "TX",
'zipCode' : "77459",
'formattedAddress' : "2880 La Quinta Dr, Missouri City, TX 77459",
'county' : "Fort Bend",
'features' : {},
'id' : "2880-La-Quinta-Dr,-Missouri-City,-TX-77459",
'longitude' : -95.551958,
'latitude' : 29.578265,
},
{
'addressLine1':"8787 Sienna Springs Blvd",
'city':"Missouri City",
'state':"TX",
'zipCode':"77459",
'formattedAddress':"8787 Sienna Springs Blvd, Apt 532, Missouri City, TX 77459",
'addressLine2':"Apt 532",
'county':"Fort Bend",
'features':{},
'id':"8787-Sienna-Springs-Blvd,-Apt-532,-Missouri-City,-TX-77459",
'longitude':-95.532226,
'latitude':29.53196
}
]
```

As you can see in the json, the "features:" element is empty and I am trying to figure out how to process it in my PropertyInformation class.

Here is my PropertyInformation class:

```
class PropertyInformation {
  String? addressLine1;
  String? city;
  String? state;
  String? zipCode;
  String? formattedAddress;
  String? assessorId;
  int? bedrooms;
  String? county;
  String? legalDescription;
  int? squareFootage;
  String? subdivision;
  int? yearBuilt;
  int? bathrooms;
  int? lotSize;
  String? propertyType;
  DateTime? lastSaleDate;
  Features? features;
  TaxAssessment taxAssessment;
  PropertyTax? propertyTaxes;
  Owner? owner;
  String? id;
  double? longitude;
  double? latitude;

  PropertyInformation({
    required this.addressLine1,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.zipCode,
    required this.formattedAddress,
    required this.assessorId,
    required this.bedrooms,
    required this.county,
    required this.legalDescription,
    required this.squareFootage,
    required this.subdivision,
    required this.yearBuilt,
    required this.bathrooms,
    required this.lotSize,
    required this.propertyType,
    required this.lastSaleDate,
    required this.features,
    required this.taxAssessment,
    required this.propertyTaxes,
    required this.owner,
    required this.id,
    required this.longitude,
    required this.latitude,
  });

  factory PropertyInformation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    
    List<Features>? listOfFeatures = [];
    Map<String, dynamic> featureList = json['features'];

    return PropertyInformation(

      addressLine1: json['addressLine1'],
      city: json['city'],
      state: json['state'],
      zipCode: json['zipCode'],
      formattedAddress: json['formattedAddress'],
      assessorId: json['assessorId'],
      bedrooms: json['bedrooms'],
      county: json['county'],
      legalDescription: json['legalDescription'],
      squareFootage: json['squareFootage'],
      subdivision: json['subdivision'],
      yearBuilt: json['yearBuilt'],
      bathrooms: json['bathrooms'],
      lotSize: json['lotSize'],
      propertyType: json['propertyType'],
      lastSaleDate: json['lastSaleDate'] == null
          ? DateTime.now()
          : DateTime.parse(json['lastSaleDate']),
      features: featureList.isEmpty == false ? Features.fromJson(json['features']) : {} as Features,
      taxAssessment: TaxAssessment.fromJson(json["taxAssessment"] as Map<String, dynamic>),
      propertyTaxes: PropertyTax.fromJson(json["propertyTaxes"] as Map<String, dynamic>), 
      owner: Owner.fromJson(json['owner']),
      id: json['id'],
      longitude: json['longitude'],
      latitude: json['latitude'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'addressLine1': addressLine1,
      'city': city,
      'state': state,
      'zipCode': zipCode,
      'formattedAddress': formattedAddress,
      'assessorId': assessorId,
      'bedrooms': bedrooms,
      'county': county,
      'legalDescription': legalDescription,
      'squareFootage': squareFootage,
      'subdivision': subdivision,
      'yearBuilt': yearBuilt,
      'bathrooms': bathrooms,
      'lotSize': lotSize,
      'propertyType': propertyType,
      'lastSaleDate': lastSaleDate?.toIso8601String(),
      'features': features?.toJson(),
       'taxAssessment': taxAssessment
           .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String?, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
       'propertyTaxes': propertyTaxes
           .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String?, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      'owner': owner?.toJson(),
      'id': id,
      'longitude': longitude,
      'latitude': latitude,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'PropertyInformation{addressLine1: $addressLine1, city: $city, state: $state, zipCode: $zipCode, formattedAddress: $formattedAddress, assessorId: $assessorId, bedrooms: $bedrooms, county: $county, legalDescription: $legalDescription, squareFootage: $squareFootage, subdivision: $subdivision, yearBuilt: $yearBuilt, bathrooms: $bathrooms, lotSize: $lotSize, lastSaleDate: $lastSaleDate, features: $features, owner: $owner, id: $id, longitude: $longitude, latitude: $latitude}';
  }
}

class Features {
  String? architectureType;
  bool? cooling;
  String? coolingType;
  String? exteriorType;
  int? floorCount;
  String? foundationType;
  bool? garage;
  String? garageType;
  bool? heating;
  String? heatingType;
  bool? pool;
  String? roofType;
  int? roomCount;
  int? unitCount;

  Features({
    required this.architectureType,
    required this.cooling,
    required this.coolingType,
    required this.exteriorType,
    required this.floorCount,
    required this.foundationType,
    required this.garage,
    required this.garageType,
    required this.heating,
    required this.heatingType,
    required this.pool,
    required this.roofType,
    required this.roomCount,
    required this.unitCount,
  });

  factory Features.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Features(
      architectureType: json['architectureType'],
      cooling: json['cooling'],
      coolingType: json['coolingType'],
      exteriorType: json['exteriorType'],
      floorCount: json['floorCount'],
      foundationType: json['foundationType'],
      garage: json['garage'],
      garageType: json['garageType'],
      heating: json['heating'],
      heatingType: json['heatingType'],
      pool: json['pool'],
      roofType: json['roofType'],
      roomCount: json['roomCount'],
      unitCount: json['unitCount'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'architectureType': architectureType,
      'cooling': cooling,
      'coolingType': coolingType,
      'exteriorType': exteriorType,
      'floorCount': floorCount,
      'foundationType': foundationType,
      'garage': garage,
      'garageType': garageType,
      'heating': heating,
      'heatingType': heatingType,
      'pool': pool,
      'roofType': roofType,
      'roomCount': roomCount,
      'unitCount': unitCount,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Features{architectureType: $architectureType, cooling: $cooling, coolingType: $coolingType, exteriorType: $exteriorType, floorCount: $floorCount, foundationType: $foundationType, garage: $garage, garageType: $garageType, heating: $heating, heatingType: $heatingType, pool: $pool, roofType: $roofType, roomCount: $roomCount, unitCount: $unitCount}';
  }
}

class Owner {
  List<String> names;
  MailingAddress mailingAddress;

  Owner({
    required this.names,
    required this.mailingAddress,
  });

  factory Owner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Owner(
      names: json['names'].cast<String?>(),
      mailingAddress: MailingAddress.fromJson(json['mailingAddress']),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'names': names,
      'mailingAddress': mailingAddress.toJson(),
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Owner{names: $names, mailingAddress: $mailingAddress}';
  }
}

class MailingAddress {
  String? id;
  String? addressLine1;
  String? city;
  String? state;
  String? zipCode;
  String? addressLine2;

  MailingAddress({
    required this.id,
    required this.addressLine1,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.zipCode,
    required this.addressLine2,
  });

  factory MailingAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MailingAddress(
      id: json['id'],
      addressLine1: json['addressLine1'],
      city: json['city'],
      state: json['state'],
      zipCode: json['zipCode'],
      addressLine2: json['addressLine2'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'addressLine1': addressLine1,
      'city': city,
      'state': state,
      'zipCode': zipCode,
      'addressLine2': addressLine2,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'MailingAddress{id: $id, addressLine1: $addressLine1, city: $city, state: $state, zipCode: $zipCode, addressLine2: $addressLine2}';
  }
}

class PropertyTax {
  int total;

  PropertyTax({
    required this.total,
  });

  factory PropertyTax.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PropertyTax(
      total: json['total'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'total': total,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'PropertyTax{total: $total}';
  }
}

class TaxAssessment {
  int value;
  int land;
  int improvements;

  TaxAssessment({
    required this.value,
    required this.land,
    required this.improvements,
  });

  factory TaxAssessment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TaxAssessment(
      value: json['value'],
      land: json['land'],
      improvements: json['improvements'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'value': value,
      'land': land,
      'improvements': improvements,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'TaxAssessment{value: $value, land: $land, improvements: $improvements}';
  }
}
```

I am thinking that when I come to an empty "features" element, I want to skip it. I am using this code but I don't know what to put when the element is empty.

This is the code I am using. If the
features: featureList.isEmpty == false ? Features.fromJson(json['features']) : {} as Features,
but this doesn't work.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Note `features` isn't empty, it's in fact `null`. An empty mapping would be `"features": {}`. If you're still accepting `null` in place of this, you'll need to explicitly check that in some way.

Comment: Thanks for your  response. You are right, "features:" is actually "features": {}. Any suggestions how to handle that?

Comment: If it's actually `"features": {}`, then that's akin to a value of `Map<String, dynamic>` (never used Dart, hope that's right!), but the map will be empty. So using the same cast, you can then pass off that empty map however you like. You'd then just treat the empty map as having no features. Why the aversion to `Features.fromJson(map['features'] as Map<String,dynamic>)`? It likely handles an empty map in just this way.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the fromMap generated by the plugin of vscode Dart Data Class Generator it will parse the json from the attributes

```
features: map['features'] != null ? Features.fromMap(map['features'] as Map<String,dynamic>) : null
```

or try with the ternary operator in the fromMap method of the Feature class

```
architectureType: json['architectureType'] ?? null
```

so the ternary only adds if it comes in the api if not it leaves null